# How to get values from an array?

Tags: php

I have an array that looks like this:

```
Array (
  [0] => 
    Array ( 
        [id] => 3434 
        [label] => some test label
    ) 
)
```

I need to get the ids and the labels from this array. so i tried this:

`foreach($results['id'] as $result) {
    echo $result['label'], '<br>';
}`

but this doesn't do anything and it gives me this error:

`PHP Notice:  Undefined index: id in`

Could someone please advice on this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
 foreach($your_array as $temp){
   echo $temp["id"];
   echo $temp["label"];
}
```

Comment: Do or do not, there is no try!  How about an explanation?

Comment: @AbraCadaver calm down

Answer (score 0):

It's multidimensional array. You can get Id and label value from array like this:

```
foreach($results as $result) 
{
    echo $result['label'].'<br>';
    echo $result['id'].'<br>';
}
```